# crontab with php doesn't work

Tags: php, cron, freebsd, postfix-mta

My situation is that I have a php file at `/root/test.php`.
And I set my root's crontab like this

`* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /root/test.php`

The content of test.php worked for generate the aliase database for postfix just like the following:

`<?php echo shell_exec("postaliases hash:/etc/aliases"); >`

I know that the test.php is successfully run by crontab.
But the shell_exec inside doesn't seem to work(I can't find my target aliases.db file under /etc/).
And I have tested use commend `php -f test.php` directly is work.

I know the situation is a little complex. But if someone can solve my problem, I will be very appreciate your for help.

Comment: Where is the source of test.php?

Comment: test.php is the testing script edited by root.Sorry for not noticed that the content was hidden between &lt; &gt;. I have updated my question.

Comment: do you know the user the crontab is running as, and the permissions on /root/test.php?  Those would be two good things to check.

Comment: Is that make any trouble if I run two shellscript just like above one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the full path to postaliases. Most likely it is not in the path of the user executing the script
2. Why do use a php script to call a shell? Just use a shellscript

Comment: It's a test code for a part of a large system writen with php. For samplify the installing process of the whole system, I would prefer using php script.I think there no problem with the pathname, but still    thanks for your reply.

Comment: I change .php script to .sh and change the content to "/usr/local/sbin/postalias hash:/etc/aliases"
But still work on "sh test.sh", not work on crontab.

Comment: do you get a mail from the cron script? do you get log messages in your syslog?

Comment: I try redirect shell output from that test shell to a debug file. I am sure that the redirection is successed, but nothing output from the "postalias".

Comment: try to replace the postalias with something that has output e.g. "echo Hello!"